# Running Batch file using Javascript - Firefox

Tags: javascript, file, batch-file

This is important for me as I have a PRN file which can be printed only through command prompt. And I want to delete that file after the print command is given.

So these 2 commands can be executed using batch file only.

And when I try to use activexobject in javascript, my firefox browsers doesnt run it.

```
<script>
MyObject = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
function Runbat()
{
MyObject.Run("\"D:\\abc.bat\"");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Examples of what you have tried?

Comment: Please try to show some code that you've run, and what has happened.

Comment: Many times a browser will block activex by default, so you should check if it is blocking it.

Comment: I have edited my questions. I have written the code there. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Together in a [html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507685/bat-calling-through-javascript-code).

I've found this one and it seems working properly :)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
            MyObject = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell")
            function Runbat()
            {
                MyObject.Run("\"D:\\test.bat\"");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Run a Program</h1>
        This script launch the file any bat File<p>
        <button onclick="Runbat()">Run bat File</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now I don't really know if you are already working with exaclty that solution, if so, and you are still facing this issue in firefox you may need to investigate a little bit more in browser security to know if that is even possible as of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980957/is-it-possible-to-run-an-exe-or-bat-file-on-onclick-in-html) states that:

> No, that would be a huge security breach. Imagine if someone could run
>
> `format c:`
>
> whenever you visted their website.

Comment: Yes, I understand your point about security breach. But I am going to provide this to just 1 person that also for his own admin panel. It;s nit going to public.  Any guidance why this is not working for Mozilla?

Comment: @Vivek 
"You mean launch an external program thru a browser window using JavaScript? No way you can do that! That's a goddamn security black hole!" 
So you would need to start configuring Mozilla Server-Sided and that (I think) is not possible for you.